# PHP, SQL limit query by php variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

PHP code defining variable sqlshowvalue

```
$sqlshowvalue = 5;
if(isset($_POST['showmore'])) {
     $sqlshowvalue += 5;
}
```

So I connect to my database and then when I run this SQL query below using the variable that I just defined above,

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC limit '$sqlshowvalue'");
```

So I am using mysqli as the method to connect to my DB and it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ..
```

The reason it gives me this error is because something in my query is wrong and what it has to do is $sqlshowvalue, because if I replace sqlshowvalue with with just the number 5 (like shown below), it works fine:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
```

So I am just wondering what I can do to make it so that the value for the limit is a PHP variable that I can be changed and the page updated.

Comment: Remove `''` from `$sqlshowvalue`, say  `DESC limit $sqlshowvalue");`

Comment: You should always check the `$result`, whether it is a resource or a boolean. If the query fails, it returns `FALSE`.

Comment: In SQL, after the keyword LIMIT, a number is expected instead of string, which has to be quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried making

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC limit '$sqlshowvalue'");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC limit ".$sqlshowvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `''` use only `$sqlshowvalue`:-

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments 
ORDER BY id DESC limit $sqlshowvalue");
```

for integer value no need of `''`

Comment: Off topic but what about if instead of the php variable $sqlshowvalue I wanted to use a javascript variable? Would I use " or ' ?

Comment: <script>
var a=5;
</script>
<?php 
$variable = "<script>document.write(a)</script>"; 
?>

Comment: Hmm, so when I do echo $variable it displays the correct one but when I put it in my sql query code it gives me that error again

Comment: This actually solved my issue. Thanks!